# Approximate probability of minimum n such that the sum of n Bernoulli random variables is greater or equal to 1000

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

Let $X_i$, $1 \le i \le N$ be iid Bernoulli random variables with $P(X_i = 1) = 0,92$. Let $N = min\{n: \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \ge 1000\}$. What is the approximate probability of $N$ being greater than 1100?

I understood that this probability could be calculated as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}P(N > 1100) &= \sum_{n=1101}^\infty P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = 1000\right) \\
&= \sum_{n=1101}^\infty \binom{n}{1000} 0,92^{1000} 0,08^{n - 1000}
\end{aligned}$$

I don't know how to approximate this expression without programming. I also tried to use simulations that got me a different answer. I'm not sure if this is not the correct expression or if my simulations are wrong. Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Look at the waiting time until success 1000, that should be negative binomial.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.